# SchedulePublish from IBus using Azure Service Bus

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, masstransit

We currently use MassTransit in combination with RabbitMQ and I now want to add support for Azure Service Bus and I would like to use the native Azure Service Bus scheduling API. I'm happy to see that MassTransit supports it, but I can't quite figure out how it works (we don't currently use message scheduling through the MassTransit API, but a custom bit of code that uses Hangfire scheduling).

The [documentation](http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/usage/scheduling/azure-sb-scheduler.html) is clear when it comes to scheduling a message from a `Consume` context, but what is less clear is how to do it from the `IBus` context.

From the `Consume` context, I only need a message instance and a delay and I can call `context.SchedulePublish`. But from an `IBus`, I only have `ScheduleSend` available (no `Publish`) and every overload expects an `Uri` for its destination. I don't know where to get this `Uri` from or what its meaning is exactly. I don't really *have* a destination, I only want to delay a *publish* of an event for a certain amount of time.

In the below code, only the "Published" and "Consumer" messages ever get consumed and logged. The "Scheduled" message which is sent with `ScheduleSend` is sent without error but not received.

https://gist.github.com/JulianRooze/bdbabce8c0b62f62dacde3b755777aa0

The log output of the `IBus` startup and the `ScheduleSend` is the following:

```
2017-06-16 19:11:09 [Debug] Subscribing Consumer: "ConsoleApp4.TestConsumer" (using default constructor)
2017-06-16 19:11:09 [Debug] Starting bus hosts...
2017-06-16 19:11:09 [Debug] Starting receive transport: sb://<omitted>.servicebus.windows.net/test_queue
2017-06-16 19:11:09 [Debug] Starting receive transport: sb://<omitted>.servicebus.windows.net/DESKTOPJULIAN_ConsoleApp4_bus_ghroyyr3bcyx635xbdkmjsiqr4?express=true&autodelete=300
2017-06-16 19:11:09 [Debug] Connecting receive transport: sb://<omitted>.servicebus.windows.net/test_queue
2017-06-16 19:11:09 [Debug] Connecting receive transport: sb://<omitted>.servicebus.windows.net/DESKTOPJULIAN_ConsoleApp4_bus_ghroyyr3bcyx635xbdkmjsiqr4?express=true&autodelete=300
2017-06-16 19:11:09 [Debug] Queue: "test_queue" ("dead letter")
2017-06-16 19:11:09 [Debug] Topic: "ConsoleApp4/Test" ("")
2017-06-16 19:11:09 [Debug] Updating subscription: "test_queue" ("ConsoleApp4/Test" -> "sb://<omitted>.servicebus.windows.net/test_queue")
2017-06-16 19:11:09 [Debug] Subscription: "test_queue" ("ConsoleApp4/Test" -> "sb://<omitted>.servicebus.windows.net/test_queue")
2017-06-16 19:11:09 [Debug] Creating queue client for sb://<omitted>.servicebus.windows.net/test_queue
2017-06-16 19:11:09 [Debug] Creating message receiver for sb://<omitted>.servicebus.windows.net/test_queue
2017-06-16 19:11:10 [Debug] Creating queue "DESKTOPJULIAN_ConsoleApp4_bus_ghroyyr3bcyx635xbdkmjsiqr4"
2017-06-16 19:11:11 [Debug] Queue: "DESKTOPJULIAN_ConsoleApp4_bus_ghroyyr3bcyx635xbdkmjsiqr4" ("express, dead letter")
2017-06-16 19:11:11 [Debug] Creating queue client for sb://<omitted>.servicebus.windows.net/DESKTOPJULIAN_ConsoleApp4_bus_ghroyyr3bcyx635xbdkmjsiqr4?express=true&autodelete=300
2017-06-16 19:11:11 [Debug] Creating message receiver for sb://<omitted>.servicebus.windows.net/DESKTOPJULIAN_ConsoleApp4_bus_ghroyyr3bcyx635xbdkmjsiqr4?express=true&autodelete=300
Started
2017-06-16 19:11:21 [Debug] GetSendEndpoint: sb://<omitted>.servicebus.windows.net/MassTransit.Scheduling/ScheduleMessage--ConsoleApp4/Test--
2017-06-16 19:11:21 [Debug] Topic: "MassTransit.Scheduling/ScheduleMessage--ConsoleApp4/Test--" ("")
2017-06-16 19:11:21 [Debug] SEND sb://<omitted>.servicebus.windows.net/MassTransit.Scheduling/ScheduleMessage--ConsoleApp4/Test-- 37090000-990b-00ff-95a9-08d4b4dab5db MassTransit.Scheduling.ScheduleMessage<ConsoleApp4.Test>
```

The queues/topcs as configured by MassTransit:

[image: The queues/topcs as configured by MassTransit]

Comment: I checked `SchedulePublish` on `IBus` for RabbitMQ and it tried to find out what the message destination address is and then calls `ScheduleSend`. So it is really not a publish as such.

Comment: The built-in support for this isn't great, unfortunately. It will get better in the next release.

Comment: When is the next release?